# What does the Music App on the phone synchronize to the Music App on the mac?

Tags: macos, iphone, music

I think it synchronizes the play and skip count only.

But I am not sure about the following:

- does the Music App synchronize deletes (from my observation it does not appear to)
- Playlists updated from the device? (it looks like it creates a new playlist on the mac)
- loves/hate?  (does not appear to do so)

Comment: What does the sync settings look like in Apple Music?  What do you have selected?

Comment: I just left it as sync everything.  Not even selecting a specific playlist.  About the only change was the reduce the bitrate to 256K AAC in case I have ALAC files

Comment: Are the songs not being synchronized?  Can you post a screen shot of your Mac and iPhone where you believe there is a discrepancy?

Comment: Songs are being synchronized just the meta data

Comment: I just manually synced a song that I tagged as "loved" and the meta data synced with no problem.  Can you post that screenshot previously requested?